# Calculating NDVI for Sentinel 2A, graph builder (SNAP)

Tags: raster, sentinel-snap

While I am trying to calculate NDVI in graph builder, I get this error:

```
Can not convert "(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)" to double.
```

Target band type is: Float32 (it comes up automatically when I load the image.